# How to link a `.lib` library using C++?

Tags: c++

How to link a `.lib` library using C++?

I've tried :

```
#pragma comment("xxx.lib")
```

Any brilliant idea, please?

Comment: Does this thread help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10847076/how-do-i-add-a-lib-file-to-link-in-visual-c-2010

Comment: @taocp, I've tried the first to add a dependency like it's suggested but that couldn't change nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using Microsoft Visual Studio:

```
#pragma comment(lib, "xxx.lib")
```

If, on the other hand, you're using GCC, then:

```
-L(directory of xxx.lib) -lxxx
```

Answer (score 4):

You can do it in two ways:

most common approach:

In Visual Studio project you specify the additional lib input:

`Project Properties -> Linker -> Input -> Additional Dependencies`

This is the preferred method, because this very system-dependent parameter is not hardcoded in the source code. In other systems the project (and it dependencies) is defined in different ways (makefile, cmake, etc...), but the same C++ sources can be used.

less common approach, directly in the source:

`#pragma comment(lib, "xxx.lib")`

This will however fail to work if you try to compile in a non-windows environment.

Answer (score 0):

There is no standard.

Depends on your build tools.  Some requires a `-l` on the command line, others require you to set properties in an IDE.

What platform are you using?

What build tools are you using?

Comment: I'm using VS 2013. And I would add `odbc32.lib` into my project.

Comment: Have you tried searching the web?  Try "MSDN Visual Studio 2013 linking libraries c++"