# SEHException Kinect V2

Tags: c#, kinect

I'm trying to run [this code from GitHub (Kinectv2HeartRate)](https://github.com/dngoins/Kinectv2HeartRate) which basically calculates the heart rate of the person in front of the kinect. But once it recognizes a face it returns this error

> An exception of type 'System.Runtime.InteropServices.SEHException' occurred in Microsoft.Kinect.Face.dll but was not handled in user code
>   Additional information: External component has thrown an exception.

at this line of code:

```
m_FaceSource = new Microsoft.Kinect.Face.FaceFrameSource(
        m_Sensor, m_CurrentTrackingId, 
        Microsoft.Kinect.Face.FaceFrameFeatures.BoundingBoxInColorSpace | 
        Microsoft.Kinect.Face.FaceFrameFeatures.BoundingBoxInInfraredSpace | 
        Microsoft.Kinect.Face.FaceFrameFeatures.PointsInColorSpace | 
        Microsoft.Kinect.Face.FaceFrameFeatures.PointsInInfraredSpace
);
```

I've run the FaceBasics code and it gives the same error, but the .exe runs perfectly. Can someone please shed some light on this problem for me?

Comment: Unrelated to the error,  but you may want to import the namespace `Microsoft.Kinect.Face` so that you don't need to keep repeating it in code - makes it a lot more readable ;)

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming `m_sensor` and `m_CurrentTrackingId` are not `null` because we wouldn't be able to guess reason behind it.

So we are left with features.

Visiting [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.kinect.face.faceframefeatures.aspx) reveals requirement to use these features.
[image]

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10847076/how-do-i-add-a-lib-file-to-link-in-visual-c-2010)  link should help you achieve adding lib file.

Comment: If a .lib file is missing, the app shouldn't even link.

Comment: I´ve added the lib already and it still gives me the same error. I'm seriously lost and I can´t find a reason for this error.

Comment: Would you mind showing code how you get these: `m_Sensor, m_CurrentTrackingId, `

Comment: m_Sensor = Microsoft.Kinect.KinectSensor.GetDefault(); line 224 and this.m_CurrentTrackingId = selectedBody.TrackingId; line 312