# How to use SFML in Visual Studio?

Tags: c++, sfml, visual-studio-2022

I wanted to compile some of my C++ SFML games that I wrote on Linux so my friends can play it but I don't know how to compile my projects in Visual Studio.

After I add `sfml2.5.1/include` path to "Additional include directories", `SFML_STATIC` to "Preprocessor definitions", `sfml 2.5.1/lib` directory to "Additional library directories" and `sfml-graphics.lib;sfml-window.lib;sfml-system.lib` to "Additional dependencies" and then run it, it says:

> fatal error LNK1181: cannot open input file 'sfml-graphics.lib'

I tried to change `sfml*.lib` to `libsfml*.a` and here is first 3 lines of  52 of what it saying:

```
1>Game.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: static class sf::RenderStates const sf::RenderStates::Default" (?Default@RenderStates@sf@@2V12@B)
1>Game.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: static class sf::Color const sf::Color::White" (?White@Color@sf@@2V12@B)
1>Game.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual class sf::Vector2<float> __cdecl sf::CircleShape::getPoint(unsigned __int64)const " (?getPoint@CircleShape@sf@@UEBA?AV?$Vector2@M@2@_K@Z)
```

What to do with this?

Comment: Add the path to `sfml-graphics.lib`  to the linker search path. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10847076/how-do-i-add-a-lib-file-to-link-in-visual-c-2010/10847128#10847128

Answer (score 1):

I recently had to do a similar thing and I found `vcpkg` very easy and convenient.
First check if `vcpkg` is already integrated with your Visual Studio installation. Since mine wasn't, I did:

```
> git clone https://github.com/Microsoft/vcpkg.git
> .\vcpkg\bootstrap-vcpkg.bat -disableMetrics
> .\vcpkg\vcpkg integrate install
```

Make the library available with:

```
> .\vcpkg\vcpkg install sfml:x64-windows
```

Now in the Visual Studio project sources just include the library headers:

```cpp
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>
```

The project should compile and link, creating a dll for the library in your build folder.

Final note: to keep `vcpkg` libraries updated:

```
> cd .\vcpkg
> git pull
> .\bootstrap-vcpkg.bat -disableMetrics
> .\vcpkg upgrade --no-dry-run
```

A pair of (outdated?) example projects: [n-body simulation](https://github.com/matgat/n-body.git), [sfml-examples](https://github.com/matgat/sfml-examples.git)

Comment: It is a bit confusing. I had started down this path, but I did not want to install vcpkg manually, as it installs with visual studio automatically. So, I had switched to this one: https://www.sfml-dev.org/tutorials/2.5/start-vc.php But now, I will switch back, and look through my KB for how to use system vcpkg. But yes, if one can get to vcpkg install it seems like they are home free. https://vcpkg.io/en/packages for me wxWidgets is another library I wanted to port. So, vcpkg was ideal just a headache.

Comment: @Phume Yeah, I heard that now `vcpkg` should be already available installing the latest Visual Studio, I'll update this answer to point out that.

Answer (score 1):

In your current project, in Visual Studio, go to "tools" on your menu. Hover down to "Command Line" menu option and select "Developer Command Prompt". If you installed vcpkg with VS this CMD will contain vcpkg, whereas a normal CMD will not. Weird, but true. From there, you can run `vcpkg new --application` to generate a manifest file, `vcpkg add port SFML`, configure CMakePresets, CMakeLists, and build and run the project.

These instructions are found on Microsoft's VCPKG documentation online.

Search and you will find.

Goodluck.